# Telegram bot on python with callback

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm using module `python-telegram-bot`.

I want to write bot somewhat similar to `@vkmusic_bot`:

1. User sends a search query with name of song to the bot
2. Bot processes this query string and sends file options menu to user
3. User chooses the song he wants and presses on respective button
4. Bot sends `.mp3` file to user

[UI example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fSmp.png)

My question is about dealing with callbacks. Especially I am confused about step 2 - how can I make a menu and how does bot parse user's choice?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I use a different framework, so I'll give you links to Telegram Bot API documentation and example in `curl`. Everything below is just an example; there may be a lot of ways to achieve your goal.

---

> how can I make a menu?

If you want to send a menu similar to your example image, use an [inline keyboard](https://core.telegram.org/bots/2-0-intro#new-inline-keyboards).

Basically a menu here is an `InlineKeyboardMarkup` [object](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardmarkup), which contains an array of  `InlineKeyboardButton` [objects](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton). Each button must have 2 properties specified:

1. `text` - this is just a caption of a button
2. `callback_data` - this property holds a text data, which will be later used by bot to determine which button was pressed by user. It is up to you how to store information in this property. *Note that the size of this property is limited to 64 bytes.*

So `callback_data` can be used to identify a particular `.mp3` file. This is somewhat like `id` of a button and an `id` of a song. Perhaps, you should store associations between file paths on your hard drive (for example) and their respective `id`'s. Bot should be able to find a file path in that database with given `id`, and then locate a file on disk.

Finally when your menu is ready, send it as `reply_markup` property in `sendMessage` [method](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage).

Simple `curl` example:

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"chat_id": <YOUR_USER_ID>, "text": "Choose the song:", "reply_markup": {"inline_keyboard": [[{"text": "song 1", "callback_data": "file78435675234"}],[{"text": "song 2", "callback_data": "file789231467982134"}],[{"text": "song 3", "callback_data": "file135423854423"}]]}}' \
https://api.telegram.org/bot<YOUR_BOT_ID>/sendMessage
```

---

> how does bot parse user's choice?

If you use inline keyboard from the example above, bot can retrieve information about user's choice from `data` property of a `CallbackQuery` [object](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery) of an incoming [update](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#update).

So when user presses a particular button in the menu, bot receives 1) `user_id` and 2) `callback_data` of that button.

With this information bot will be able to locate desired `.mp3` file on disk and then use `sendAudio` [method](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendaudio) to send this file to user.